# Printing special characters on bluetooth printer

Tags: android

I have an application where I should be able to print on a bluetooth printer, Zebra ZQ320, but I have some problems with specific characters, the only thing in the project related to the printer configuration is a class called "UtileriaImpresion" in which configuration for zebra is added IMZ320 a previously used model which presented the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Without more details or seeing some code, that looks like UTF-8 printed as ISO-8859-1.  In the ZPL, you need to set the printer to use UTF-8, via `^CI28`.

Comment: Best would be to show the exact ZPL you are sending to the printer.  That way, I can comment on it directly.  But in regards to the `^CI28`, you just need to include it near the top of your label format, typically soon after the `^XA` and before any `^FD` fields.

Comment: I believe that code is producing the text to substitute into a ZPL template? I do not see where the ZPL is actually being generated. You will need to modify the code that either generates the ZPL, or the ZPL template file.